# MySQL Query not working as expected - returning more than one response

Tags: mysql

I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT
 a.*, 
 (CASE  concat(question_id, type)
 WHEN @curType 
 THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
 ELSE @curROw := 1 AND @curType := concat(question_id, type) END) + 0 AS rank
 FROM ul_attempt_responses a
 INNER JOIN us_attempts b ON a.attempt_id = b.id
 WHERE b.user_id = 1  and response IS NOT NULL AND trim(response) != ''  and b.authenticated = 1 ORDER BY question_id DESC, type DESC, id DESC) aa
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY question_id ASC, type asc;
```

The above query should be give me the latest response, on the attempt_id and also just give me one, however, it is giving me 2 or more responses.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cd26

I need a query that will Get the last response of user for all attempts. If in attempt has a question answered, and the next attempt has no answer, get the response of the former attempt.

Comment: Just a little aside http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: My actual problem is the above query kinda works, but it should give me 1 response per question_id however it is giving me like 2 or more

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (
  SELECT
 * from  
 (CASE  concat(question_id, type)
  WHEN @curType 
 THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
 ELSE @curROw := 1 AND @curType := concat(question_id, type) END) + 0 AS      rank
 FROM ul_attempt_responses a
 INNER JOIN us_attempts b ON a.attempt_id = b.id
 WHERE b.user_id = 1  and response IS NOT NULL AND trim(response) != ''  and         b.authenticated = 1 ORDER BY question_id DESC, type DESC, id DESC) aa
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY question_id ASC, type asc;))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this much more efficiently with an anti-join:

```
SELECT ar.*
FROM us_users u
JOIN us_attempts a1
  ON a1.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN us_attempts a2
  ON a2.user_id = u.id
  AND a2.id < a1.id
JOIN ul_attempt_responses ar
  ON ar.attempt_id = a1.id
WHERE u.id = 1 AND a2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY question_id, type
```

If you want to learn more about this technique, check out the book [SQL Antipatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557).

Comment: The above is not what I require: I need a query that will Get the last response of user for all attempts. If in attempt has a question answered, and the next attempt has no answer, get the response of the former attempt.

Comment: My query kinda does that, but it is returning me more than one row for one question_id, I need it return the latest response only.

Comment: What is a response? Show us the expected output. The query I provided shows all of the responses for the latest attempt from the "us_attempts" table for the specified user. What are you ordering if you're not expecting multiple records from ul_attempt_responses?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM (
SELECT sort.,
 (CASE  concat(question_id,type)
  WHEN @curType 
  THEN @curRow := coalesce(@curRow,0) + 1
  ELSE @curROw := 1 AND @curType := concat(question_id,type) END) + 1 AS rank
 from 
 (SELECT
  a. 
  FROM ul_attempt_responses a
  LEFT JOIN us_attempts b ON a.attempt_id = b.id
  WHERE b.user_id = 3 AND response IS NOT NULL AND trim(response) != '' AND b.authenticated = 1
ORDER BY question_id, type, id DESC) sort) final WHERE rank = 2;`

That is the Answer that I was looking for.